# I keep getting an error when I try to log into chat?

Tags: support, chat

Since my browser doesn't allow for third-party cookies (which is a deliberate choice) I have to try to log into chat via StackExchange.com -- however, repeated attempts simply yield a blank page (no HTML or CSS) that reads this error:

> No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting

Why am I getting this error? How can I work around it? If the answer could include an option that doesn't require me to allow third-party cookies, that would be awesome.

For completeness: I'm using Firefox Portable on Windows 7. I do not have any ad blocker running, though I do use an extension that masks my IP address.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious thing — configuring your browser to send the Referer header to *.stackexchange.com? By the way, an extension cannot possibly mask your IP address (a proxy can, and maybe you have an extension that makes you use an external proxy, but that's not the same thing).

Comment: @Gilles In what way is that obvious? I would never have thought to do that. I'll go figure out how to do that and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Kasuchiko: I think it was obvious when it said *"may be due to a browser setting"*. Dunno. I'm no expert.

Comment: @Gilles I wasn't able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: We can hardly help you if you don't tell us more about how you configured your browser. Normally a browser does send a `Referer:` header, and I wouldn't be surprised if Stack Exchange's authentication relied on this. Have you disabled sending of `Referer` through a browser setting or extension or proxy? Can you log in to chat with a fresh, unconfigured profile or with another browser?

Comment: Oh, I just discovered http://chat.stackexchange.com/help which reports whether various features that chat uses are working. Which ones are ok and which ones are not?